# How to set Chrome driver for selenium/Webdriver in Jmeter non-gui using Command prompt?

Tags: jmeter, chromedriver

I am executing the load test plan using the non-GUI mode of Jmeter and I want to set the chrome driver using non-GUI mode. I have used the below command for executing the test plan and storing the results.

`jmeter -n -t D:\JmeterSeleniumScripts\LCOrderSummryReport.jmx -l D:\JmeterSeleniumScripts\lcOrderSummaryResults.jtl -f -e -o D:\JmeterSeleniumScripts\dashboard`

**Can anyone please help me how can I set chrome driver using command prompt.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a local JMeter property this way:

```
-J[prop_name]=[value]
```

In your case it may be :

```
jmeter -n -t WebDriverSampler.jmx -JChromeDriverPath=c:\soft\webdriver\chromedriver.exe
```

Read defined properties in JMeter with [function _P](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and use it in "Chrome" tab of jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config:

```
${__P(ChromeDriverPath)}
```

You can pass and use any parameters this way.

[image]

Do not forget to put a default value in case you run the script without passing that JMeter property like:

```
${__P(ChromeDriverPath,c:\soft\webdriver\chromedriver.exe)}
```

Comment: So, I have to use like this `${__P(ChromeDriverPath,c:\soft\webdriver\chromedriver.exe)}` in path to chrome driver ??

Comment: Indeed, just try now)

Comment: Yes I have tried it before like this, but that didn't work ,,,,now I used only like this `__P(chromeDriverPath)` and in command prompt I used like this `jmeter -n -t D:\JmeterSeleniumScripts\LCOrderSummryReport.jmx -l D:\JmeterSeleniumScripts\lcOrderSummaryResults.jtl -f -e -o D:\JmeterSeleniumScripts\dashboard -JUsers=4 -JRampUp=8 -JchromePathDriver=D:\chromeDriverForJmeter\chromedriver.exe` and it's work fine now !!